# How do I correlate my original data with clustered data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a distance matrix presents the distance matrix for pairwise elements
such as

```
    A B C D .....
A   n1 n2 n3
B n1    
C n2 n4
D n3 n5 ....... 
E.........
```

i input the array like for clustering

```
 arry=  [ 0 n1, n2, n3..
   n1.......
   n2 n4
   n3 n5 ]


Y=sch.linkage(arry,'single')
cutoff=1e-6
T=sch.fcluster(Y, cutoff,'distance')
print T

Z=sch.dendrogram(Y, color_threshold=cutoff)
```

my fcluster output is like 
[ 4 10 12  1  5 13  2 11  1  7  8  3 14  6 10 16  9 15  1  7]
from a previous poster of others 
[Clustering with scipy - clusters via distance matrix, how to get back the original objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724635/clustering-with-scipy-clusters-via-distance-matrix-how-to-get-back-the-origin)

I understand 
the output T[i] only presents the number of element in a cluster ..how I link the original element A, B ,C ,D ,E..... elements with the cluster result and the dendrogram? and lab them properly into my figures.

Comment: Seriously, read the scipy documentation.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I understand the output T[i] only presents the number of element in a cluster*..."

`T[j]` is the "cluster number" of the j-th data point.  That is, `fcluster` provides the assignments of data points to clusters.  So, for example, if there are five data points, and `fcluster` puts the first, second and last in cluster 1 and the others in cluster 2, the return value of `fcluster` will be `array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1])`.

Here's a demo that shows how you can pull that data apart.  For convenience, I've used `fclusterdata` instead of the combination of `linkage` and `fcluster`.  `fclusterdata` returns the same thing as `fcluster`.

```
import numpy as np

def cluster_indices(cluster_assignments):
    n = cluster_assignments.max()
    indices = []
    for cluster_number in range(1, n + 1):
        indices.append(np.where(cluster_assignments == cluster_number)[0])
    return indices

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata

    # Make some test data.
    data = np.random.rand(15,2)

    # Compute the clusters.
    cutoff = 1.0
    cluster_assignments = fclusterdata(data, cutoff)

    # Print the indices of the data points in each cluster.
    num_clusters = cluster_assignments.max()
    print "%d clusters" % num_clusters
    indices = cluster_indices(cluster_assignments)
    for k, ind in enumerate(indices):
        print "cluster", k + 1, "is", ind
```

Typical output:

```
4 clusters
cluster 1 is [ 0  1  6  8 10 13 14]
cluster 2 is [ 3  4  5  7 11 12]
cluster 3 is [9]
cluster 4 is [2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it is much clear the meaning of cluster_number in T[i]! :-) but how I link this data with the dendrogram generated? it looks like it would be easy if the T[i] points to the same cluster number.   but if T[i] are not the same,  how can i figure out which one includes which?

Comment: Have you read the documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage ?

Comment: yes, I think i know that docs. Thanks all the same although!. one more issues is in the tick/axis label for the hierarchy plot shows the index of the matrix for clustering. I can hide it and add one bar with the my elements names on it. but is there any better way or any exits method/function already help us do that?